# Finding an element of an array that maximises the key function with recursion in python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, lambda, max

So I need to find the element in the array that will give the maximum value when inputting to the key. Also, if there is more than one element that does that, the first one must be returned. Furthermore, the key parameter must be optional; if not provided, the function must return the first largest element. So far I've come up with

```
def recursive_max(seq, key = lambda x: x):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        m = recursive_max(max(seq, key), key) .......
```

I'm quite stuck. I don't fully understand recursion but here are the steps I think I need to take.

```
1) Get element from the list
2) Input the key into the function
3) Initialize the max
4) Compare across the sequence (which is my array)
```

I'm quite confused how to write this is in code.

Comment: Why is this recursive?

Comment: Reading up on logical or in Python might help - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: it must be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

If recursion is the requirement, you can just go

```
def recursive_max(seq, key=lambda x: x):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        return max(seq[0], recursive_max(seq[1:], key), key=key)
```

Here you compare the first element of the array with the maximum of the rest of the array.

Note that the version above is not tail recursive (although it does not matter in Python --- or, at least, in CPython). A tail-recursive version would look like

```
def recursive_max2(seq, key=lambda x: x):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        return _recursive_max(seq[0], seq[1:], key)

def _recursive_max(x, xs, key):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return _recursive_max(max(x, xs[0], key=key), xs[1:], key)
```